# Is there anything wrong with using "through" with "email"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Can somebody tell if there’s anything wrong with this sentence, please?

> I just sent the authorization to you **through** my student email.

I thought "through" wasn't used with "email." Should it be "by" or "via email"? I Googled and found this [site](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/through-email-by-email-via-email.3086548/) but the answer posted lacked detail.

Comment: Would you tell us more about the context and your specific problem with this question?

Comment: “Through my student email” that’s my problem. I thought “through” wasn’t used with “email”

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22through+Email%22&rlz=1C1AJZK_enUS767US767&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivlq_T467pAhUWqJ4KHRWbBnEQ_AUICSgA&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1

Comment: Some might argue "through" does not work, but I've used it and saw it being used in academia a lot. So, I would say there is no problem with using "through". However, I myself usually use prepositions "in" and "via".

Comment: There is no single "grammatically correct" preposition to connect the message and the medium *(authorisation + email)* - ***through, by, with, using, via, over, on*** are all at least *credible* choices, and I'm sure there are other possibilities.

Comment: sent x to you **in** an email.